# React Native - Redux - Error: undefined is not an object - _renderRow listView

Tags: listview, react-native, redux, datasource, react-redux

I am new to `react native` using `Redux` and I am developing a `listView` displaying some `contacts` with `firstName` and `lastName`. And when I press on a row, the row is supposed to change its style.

The rendering an initialisation happens fine, but when I press on the row, I get this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.contact.firstName')
```

I presume that the object I am passing to the `datasource` is empty but I don't really know how to get around it. I tried to add a bool to the state that would be `true` when the `datasource` is loaded, but it did not work.

This is my code:

```
class ParticipantsListComponent extends Component<StateProps, { dataSource: ListViewDataSource }> {
constructor(props: StateProps) {
    super(props);
    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2 });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.participants)
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: StateProps) {
    if (nextProps.participants !== this.props.participants) {
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(nextProps.participants)
        });
    }
}

_renderRow = (entry: { contact: Contact, selected: boolean }, section: number, row: number) => {
    return (
        <ParticipantsListItem
            contact={entry.contact}
            selected={entry.selected} />
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyles}>
            <TextInput style={styles.textInputStyles} />
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        </View>
    );
 }
}

export const ParticipantsList: ComponentClass<void> = connect(
(state: StoreState, ownProps: void): StateProps => ({
    participants: state.contacts.contacts.map(contact => 
    ({ 
        contact, 
        selected: state.newTopic.participants.contains(contact.id) 
    })).toArray()
}),
dispatch => ({})
)(ParticipantsListComponent) as ComponentClass<any>;
```

Basically I need to find a way to ensure that the data I am passing to the `dataSource` is not undefined. If someone knows a solution, I would be glad to hear it.

You will find the code for the `ParticipantListItemComponent` right below:

```
class ParticipantsListItemComponent extends Component<OwnProps & DipatchProps, void> {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress(this.props.contact.id)} style={styles.container} >
          <Text style={styles.name}>{!this.props.selected ? this.props.contact.firstName : ''} {this.props.contact.lastName}</Text>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export const ParticipantsListItem: ComponentClass<OwnProps> = connect(
  (state: void, ownProps: void): {} => ({}),
  dispatch => ({
    onPress: (id: string) => dispatch(toggleParticipant(id))
  })
)(ParticipantsListItemComponent);
```

Comment: Can you show us your `connect` function?

Comment: Yes of course, I did not even notice I forgot it

Comment: I think your problem lies within the `ParticipantsListItem` component, since the initial rendering is working. Sorry for asking again, but, do you mind posting that component as well?

Comment: No problem, I do it right away

Comment: Could it be that you are using `cloneWithRowsAndSections` instead of `cloneWithRows` in your `componentWillReceiveProps` method?

Comment: You saved me!! Dude thanks, I have been struggling all day on this bug

Comment: Haha glad to hear it. Maybe you should answer the question with the fix so that it gets closed :)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use `cloneWithRows` instead of `cloneWithRowsAndSections`.